# Why use boost::ice_or instead of || and boost::ice_and instead of && in enable_if?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, enable-if

As question states, is there a reason why people use the struct version over the normal conditionals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An excerpt from the [Boost Coding Guidelines for Integral Constant Expressions](http://www.boost.org/development/int_const_guidelines.html):

> **Don't use logical operators in integral constant expressions; use template meta-programming instead.**
>
> The header  contains a number of workaround templates, that fulfil the role of logical operators, for example instead of:
>
> > `INTEGRAL_CONSTANT1 || INTEGRAL_CONSTANT2`
>
> Use:
>
> > `::boost::type_traits::ice_or<INTEGRAL_CONSTANT1,INTEGRAL_CONSTANT2>::value`
>
> Rationale: A number of compilers (particularly the Borland and Microsoft compilers), tend to not to recognise integral constant expressions involving logical operators as genuine integral constant expressions. The problem generally only shows up when the integral constant expression is nested deep inside template code, and is hard to reproduce and diagnose.

So I'd say never on a compliant compiler. (But if you need to support non-compliant compilers, use it.)

Comment: "particularly the Borland and **Microsoft** compilers" Oh sh...! VS210 here. :| Thanks for providing that snippet!

Comment: @Xeo: No problem. It's a shame they don't list the compilers, but I really doubt VC2010 needs it.

Comment: @Xeo - They surely mean VC6 which is notorious both for being too widely used and being very pre-standard. VS2010 has no such problems.

Comment: Thanks! And as I'm not a friend of too much double-colons and angle brackets, this makes me a happy coder. :) If anything does fail though, I'm gonna know why.